# How to combine two Datasources in SSRS

Tags: sql

my report have two different Dataset(Dataset1 and Dataset2) both is connected  to different Data sources . Field Name is derived from Dataset1 and ID is derived  from Dataset2.I want to display the Name in textbox based on the ID derived  from Dataset2.Can anyone please suggest best option other than linked server.

Answer (score 0):

The only tools that SSRS provides to solve this problem are [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) and [LookupSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx).  These functions do require SSRS 2008 R2, and don't scale all that well (lookups between two large datasets can become quite slow).  If there's any way you can accomplish this at the database level (linked server, ETL the data to one location, replication, etc), that would probably be better.